# Will I violate the impersonation policy if I republish my old app with new package name in my new account?

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, google-play-services

I published an app to beta testing. There is 10+ installs for that app now and it is still in testing release. It has in-app purchases, but no one paid anything yet.

Now I want to do production release for that app **with different package name *from different google developer account***.

If I unpublish the app and republish it in another developer account with new package name, will I violate the impersonation policy.

If yes, what should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer ownership of your old app from your old account to the new account. Then you can unlist the old app and list the new one. And of course you can legally publish both without restrictions since both apps belong to the same owner.

Comment: What do you mean by "unlisting the app"? As far as I know Google wont let you delete already published apps.  I mean will I be able to change package name?

Comment: Google Play console > "The app you want to delete/remove/unlist" > Store presence > Pricing & distribution > Unpublish

Comment: Dont you think it would work out if unlist/unpublish the testing app and release new from another account?

Comment: I also don't think there is an issue with that. But keep in mind if you want to transfer ownership have all the app's needed credentials i.e.SHA256 and follow instructions from this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en)